# Django: can't load images but static files OK

Tags: django, file-upload

I'm learning Django, and I've spent a week+ trying to display images in my app. I think that there's an issue with my settings but I'm perplexed since the static files are loading, though the images with similar settings are not.

What confuses me so much is that my static files are loaded ok at MEDIA_ROOT/static, but that image files aren't found at MEDIA_ROOT/media. Based on settings.py, static seems like it would live at
`# C:\Users\...\final\static` but it's clear that this isn't true.

**structure**

```
├── final
│   ├── dogtracks
│   │   ├── static
|   │   │   ├── dogtracks
│   ├── media
|   │   ├── images
```

**settings.py**

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
...
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media') # C:\Users\...\final\media
```

**models.py**

```
class Animal(models.Model):
      ...
      photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='images', null=True, blank=True)
      ...
    

class AnimalForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Animal
        fields = ['name', 'breed', 'species', 'birthday', 'photo']
```

**html**

```
{% if pet.photo %}
<img src="final{{ pet.photo.url }}" />
{% else %}
<img src="{% static 'dogtracks/noun-pet.png' %}" />
{% endif %}
```

I've read dozens of answers here on SO and gone through tutorials online. I've moved the location of my images folder to try to show these images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add path of **`MEDIA_URL`** and **`MEDIA_ROOT`** in urls.py of project directory

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("", include("myapp.urls")),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),

]+static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT) # Add this
```

Comment: This did it! I had a similar line in my APP-LEVEL settings.py but not in my PROJECT-LEVEL settings.py.
I also modified the last line to:
    `urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,...)`
and added to the top:
    `from django.conf import settings
    from django.conf.urls.static import static`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you made a mistake in the template..Remove `final`

```
    {% if pet.photo %}
      <img src="final{{ pet.photo.url }}" />
    {% else %}
      <img src="{% static 'dogtracks/noun-pet.png' %}" />
    {% endif %}
```

Should be:

```
{% if pet.photo %}
  <img src="{{ pet.photo.url }}" />
{% else %}
  <img src="{% static 'dogtracks/noun-pet.png' %}" />
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Thank you - the "final" was from an earlier version where I was testing paths.